# Icon with text in a well Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to using bootstrap and I'm trying to customize a well with an icon on the left and some text on the right. In doing so, I want the div with the icon to have a green background like this:

[image: The Icon on the left with green background and text on right]

I've been able to get this but the green background on the icon div is not covering the whole area, possibly due to some padding issues. Can someone demonstrate this with an example?
I've got this so far:

[image: progress]

Here's the html:

```css
.well {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid #D3D9E3;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 rgba(185, 194, 208, 0.41);
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  .well-text {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  background-color: white;
  .well-icon {
    margin-right: 20px;
    //background-color: #98DDA6;
    img {
      width: 100px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="well well-graphic">
      <div class="well-icon hide-xs col-sm-2">
        <svg class="icon icon-magnifying-glass-search">
                 <use xlink:href="../assets/img/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-magnifying-glass-search"></use>
                    </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="well-text well-color">
          <p>The .well-graphic class is used for Callout Boxes w/ icon.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check to see if your css file is correct, because what you showed us here is not syntax-correct.

Comment: @LazarNikolic I just made the edits

Comment: Do you use vanilla css? If yes: nesting don't work. You have to write `.well .well-text` manually.

Comment: As @Emaro said, you cannot nest css class definitions. You can do that on less and scss but not in vanila css

Comment: I am using scss. Not Vanilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some change in html and css files.
You will probably have to change some margin as I don't have the picture.
But the background is good for me and I hope for you too ;-)

HTML file:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="well well-graphic row">
                    <div class="well-icon hide-xs col-sm-2">
                        <svg class="icon icon-magnifying-glass-search">
                            <use xlink:href="../assets/img/icons/symbol-defs.svg#icon-magnifying-glass-search"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="well-text well-color">
                            <p>The .well-graphic class is used for Callout Boxes w/ icon.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS file:

```
.well {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid #d3d9e3;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 rgba(185, 194, 208, 0.41);
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
.well-text {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.well {
  margin: 15px 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1.5px solid #d3d9e3;
}
.well-icon {
  background-color: #98dda6;
}
```